# Как с delphi выполнять определённое действие каждые сутки?

Tags: delphi

Знаю что у компонента timer лимит 5 минут а мне нужно 24 часа. Какими методами можно такую вещь сделать?

Comment: Вопрос неполон. Требуется ли чтобы пользовательское приложение висело в фоне? Или нужно с помощью ОС запустить какое-то действие программы?

Comment: Подразумевается, что компьютер всё это время будет включён?

Comment: а какая разница? висит приложение или нет, нужно что то выполнять или нет?
Человек спросил как обойти ограничение таймера всего лишь.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, в данном случае будет куда эффективнее использовать cron или стандартный планировщик, которые запустят приложение. Cron для windows можно взять к примеру [здесь](http://www.nncron.ru/). Или почитать [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149545/). Это проверенные годами способы.

Если же приложение должно работать постоянно и нужно выполнять какое то действие, то можно использовать трюк "[с запретом одновременного запуска более одной копии программы](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/only_one_app_instance2.html)". То есть, крон в любом случае запускает программу (например с определенным ключом). Если в памяти уже есть запущенная ранее копия, то просто посылается сообщение и нужное действие выполняет предыдущая копия.

Если же нужно, что бы все обрабатывалось внутри программы, то придется использовать либо таймеры, либо отдельный тред. Внутри обработчика нужно запросить текущую дату-время (например с помощью `now()` и сравнить с предыдущим запомненным значением. Если время ещё много, то таймер заводим на 2/3 интервала (можно на половину). Если время заканчивается, то можно завести таймер прицельно.

Но придется учесть следующее:

- запоминать в файл/реестр время последнего срабатывания
- помнить о том, что не всегда в сутках 24 часа (например, когда переводят часы, то либо 23 либо 25).
- помнить, что пользователь может взять и перевести часы (либо синхронизация времени переведет автоматично), поэтому нужно определиться, что делать в этом случае.
- сделать защиту от двойного срабатывания
- сделать защиту от нахлеста (это когда обработчик работает более 24 часов).

Answer (score 0):

Объявляешь глобальную переменную пускай будет **tt:Integer**

в событии таймера пишешь такой код:

```
inc(tt);
If tt> 288 then
begin
tt:=0;
Timer1.enable:=false;
// Выполняешь что тебе нужно
Timer1.enable:=true;
end;
```

288 это если у таймера интервал 5 минут, если интервал другой то пересчитаешь

Comment: плохое решение. нет учета погрешности. Плюс, если приложение закрыли (перезапустили компьютер), то оно начнет отсчет заново.